# the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges implies the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\sin (k\pi x)$ converges for $x$ irrational

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ be a convergent series. Then can we obtain $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\sin (k\pi x)$ converges for $x$ irrational?

If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges absolutely, then I can obtain that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\sin (k\pi x)$ converges for all $x$. But I do not know how to deal with the case  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges conditionally...

Comment: I believe this is *not* true for conditionnally converging series. Take e.g. $x=\frac{1}{\pi}$ with $a_k=\sin(k)$.

Comment: @Joce, do you mean $a_{k} = (\sin k)/k$?

Comment: @sos440 : See http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txte/2/txe3ec2p.htm

Comment: @Joce : I believe that link you give is mistaken and instead intended to say that $sin(k)$ is bounded rather than convergent. $sin(k)$ diverges by the n'th term test and even by representing as a geometric series as they have done $|e^i|=1$ and hence the geometric series is divergent.

Comment: @uqtredd1: you're right indeed. But thus $\sin(k)/k$ is conditionally convergent, while $\sin^2(k)/k$ will not be convergent, as we can decompose it into a positive series and a subsample bounded from below by a series in $\alpha/k$, $\alpha>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this proof](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txte/2/txe3ec2p.htm), $\sum_{k>0} \sin(k)$ is bounded, and from [Dirichlet's test](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txte/2/txe3ea2e.htm#2), $\sum_{k>0} \sin(k)/k$ converges conditionally. However, for $x=1/\pi$, $\sum_{k>0} \sin(k\pi x)\sin(k)/k > \sum_{k' \in C} \alpha/k'$ where $0<\alpha<1$ and $C$ is a subsample of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $card(C \cup \{1,...N\})\geq \beta N$, $\beta>0$ depends on $\alpha$. Thus $\sum_{k' \in C} 1/k'$ diverges.